# Parse HTML in a mobile services custom api

Tags: node.js, azure-mobile-services

I need to parse the response HTML in my custom api, so I tried to use cheerio module. Although, I'm getting the error:

Cannot find module 'cheerio'

What do I have to do to add other npm modules?

Comment: [npmjs.org](https://www.npmjs.org/): "*Any package can be installed by using [`npm install`](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/install.html).*" Cheerio also lists [*Installation* instructions](https://www.npmjs.org/package/cheerio#readme). Also, "[*Using Node.js Modules with Windows Azure applications*](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/nodejs-use-node-modules-windows-azure-apps/)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install additional Node modules you'll need to first turn on Script Source Control for your mobile service (go to the Dashboard and look on the right side under "Quick Glance").  Once you've done that, you can clone the repository your scripts are in locally and then install Node modules and push your changes back to your Mobile Service.  You can do this by editing the package.json file or using npm install with the --save parameter to edit the json file for you.   For more information, check out this post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azuremobile/archive/2014/01/20/support-for-package-json-in-azure-mobile-services.aspx.